# Evaluating a greater than comparrison entered in a form against a provided Long value. MySQL/Java

Tags: java, mysql, compare

I have a table with a list of items that I need to be able to configure so that when I get a call from a web service I can compare the Long provided against the operator the user entered to pick the correct one.

Sample Data:

```
ID     PropertyID (INT)     Compare (varchar)
1      55                   >9
2      55                   <=9
```

In this example I'm getting the ID 55 from the web service and an integer/long (e.x. 4). And I want to pick the correct row from my table. In the website the "PropertyID" and "Compare" columns of the table are user configurable.

How would I pick the correct row? Ideally I would have MySQL do the comparison. But if that's not possible I could pull all rows with "55" as the property Id and then have Java do some magic to do the comparison.

With my example I would get row ID 2 since "4<=9".

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Expression Language (SpEL) to evaluate the expression at runtime. For reference, please check
https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

Or you can also check at project [Evalx](https://github.com/uklimaschewski/EvalEx)